# Remove the colon if it's the first character

Tags: php, regex

I would like to remove the colon only if its the first character of a string. I have tried the following but it doesnt work. Any help would be appreciated:

```
//remove the colon if its the first character..

$pattern = '/^:/';
$replace = '';
$tweet = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $tweet);
```

Comment: Are you sure your code was ok in the first place? the colon `:` doesn't have to be escaped. Maybe you needed something like `/^:+/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

escape the colon:

```
$pattern = '/^\\:/';
```

Comment: I must admit I'm baffled by this. The colon is not a regex metacharacter, so it doesn't have to be escaped for the regex engine. I also don't know why it would have to be escaped from string processing. And if it *was* necessary to escape it, you'd need a single backslash, not two, because those would encode a literal backslash. So all in all I don't understand how @LukeBream's problem arises in the first place, and how this answer can solve the problem. Can you enlighten me?

Comment: @TimPietzcker as for the double backslash - just a habit from python. it works with just one backslash, and the expressions are identical in meaning AFAIK. as for the colon, see the documentation for `preg_quote`: `The special regular expression characters are: . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`

Comment: What is the meaning of `:` in a PHP regex?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I know one use of it `[:alnum:], [:alpha:], etc`. e.g.: `echo preg_replace('/[[:alnum:]]+/', '', '...and then...');`

Comment: apparently it can also be used in the expression `(?:...)` which is `A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.`

Comment: just realised it didnt fix the problem. But I have done so now y adding the colon into an earlier exwcuted regex statement. `$pattern = '/@([a-zA-Z0-9:_]+)/';`

Answer (score 2):

You can also put the colon in a set by itself, which may be easier to read:

```
$pattern = '/^[:]/';
```